# Powershell: How to Delete all Files of Specific Type Except in One Folder

Tags: powershell

In the following PowerShell script, it quickly gets rid of any files it finds in the `bin` and `obj` folders where the script lives.  However, I want to update it to ignore a specific folder.  How can I do that if I want to ignore `/website/bin/` and `/website/obj/`, for example?

```
Get-ChildItem .\ -include bin,obj -Recurse | foreach ($_) { remove-item $_.fullname -Force -Recurse }
```

Comment: Pipe your `Get-ChildItem` to `Where Fullname -notmatch '/website/(bin|obj)/'` provided that your system's directory separator character is `/`. If it is backslash, you will need to backslash escape the backslashes.

Comment: Also, the `foreach` there is not necessary, you can pipe `gci` directly to `remove-item` and the `-include` doesn't seem to be needed either. Adding to @AdminOfThings answer, the oneliner should be `Get-ChildItem . -Recurse | where FullName -NotMatch '/website/(bin|obj)/' | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force`

Comment: Do you want to create an answer though?  